# How does Postfix handle conflicting aliases?

Tags: email, postfix, alias

I've got several alias files being used as sources for virtual aliases in Postfix, one of which is auto-generated. Sometimes, this one contains aliases that conflict with those declared in static files; how does Postfix decide which alias to prefer?

**Scenario 1**

static:

```
postmaster@my.domain authorised-user@my.domain
```

dynamic:

```
postmaster@my.domain wrong-user@other.domain
```

Can I force it to choose my static one over another? I can't exercise control over the dynamic file, so I need some measure of protection here.

Desired result: postmaster@my.domain -> authorised-user@my.domain

**Scenario 2**

static:

```
webmaster@my.domain user1@my.domain
```

dynamic:

```
webmaster@my.domain user2@other.domain
```

Sometimes I need to add temporary users to an alias, so they go into the dynamic file; can these be merged in some cases instead of overriding as above?

Desired result: webmaster@my.domain -> user1@my.domain, user2@my.domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Postfix documentation, any conflict is resolved by precedence: first come, first served.

Comment: I've not been able to find that in the docs - have you got a reference, please?

Comment: @IainHallam Not off hand, but it may be in the main.cf file. ...I'd go look, but our mail server is down and I'm focused on that right now...

Comment: I don't see it in main.cf or the man pages, but this does seem to work - the first one to define an alias is definitive and later definitions are ignored.